# Deleting cookies and temporary files

Tags: xubuntu

I have installed "Xubuntu" on my notebook and I would like to find out how to delete all cookies and temporary files through the "Xubuntu" terminal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Firefox:

```
rm ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/cookies.sqlite
rm ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/*.sqlite ~/.mozilla/firefox/*default/sessionstore.js
rm -r ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/*.default/*
```